# Make ToolStripItemCollection Property

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu, menuitem

How can I make a `ToolStripItemCollection` Property for a `ContextMenuStrip`. I thought it would be simple like this

```
ContextMenuStrip _Menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
public ToolStripItemCollection MenuItems
{
    get { return _Menu.Items; }
    set { _Menu.Items = value; }
}
```

but that does not work.

Comment: **How** doesn't it work? Does it explode?

Comment: Why are you making the property writable?

Comment: Because i want to Get and Set the ContextMenuStrip's items collection via a custom control

Comment: Hey, did you manage to figure it out? :-)

Comment: Unfortunately no @derape

Answer (score 0):

Instead in set do something like this:

```
public ToolStripItemCollection MenuItems
{
   get { return _Menu.Items; }
   set 
   {
      _Menu.Items.Clear();
      foreach(var elem in value)
      {
         _Menu.Items.Add(elem);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Value cannot be null; Parameter name: Value

Comment: could you add call stack? I wrote this code on tablet without Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

`ToolStripItemCollection` is a *mutable* type, meaning that you can add and remove items from an existing instance.

You should make your property read-only; callers should not be able to create a new instance of the collection to replace the old one.

If you want it to work with the designer, you will also need to add `[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]`.